# Laravel Paginator with post form data search with session stores

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

i have searching routes with get and post. First time users select search filters from home page then it submit it hit on index controller search with form data and return correct results with pagination  when i click on pages it does not show any thing.

```
Route::post('search', 'SearchController@index');
Route::get('search', 'SearchController@index');
```

And i have index controller for search with post first time and with session like this.

```
    public function index(Request $request)
        {
           if( Request::get('select_menu') !='' ){
                $conditions = array();
                $conditions['city'] = Request::get('city');
                $conditions['area'] = Request::get('area');
                $conditions['purpose'] = Request::get('status');
                $results = Property::where($conditions)->whereBetween('price', array(1000, 10000))->paginate(6);
                Session::set('formDataSession', $conditions);
            }
        elseif(Session::has('formDataSession')){
                $getSession = Session::get('formDataSession');
                $conditions = array();
                $conditions['city'] = $getSession['city'];
                $conditions['area'] = $getSession['area'];
                $conditions['purpose'] = $getSession['purpose'];
                $results = Property::where($conditions)->whereBetween('price', array(1000, 10000))->paginate(6);

            }
    return view('search', array('page' => 'search','results'=>$results));
}
```

Comment: Check if session variables are set up, and what you get returned from query.

Comment: it return me empty data. but when i print session there im getting it all data in session in ifelse condition

Comment: When storing use one of those: $request->session()->put('key', 'value') or 
session(['key' => 'value']) and retrieve with session('key'). Try that.

Comment: bro Tim i have no issue with session it's saving correct and return proper value when we get.

Comment: And in results you get proper values? Then try returning view as @Sarnodeep suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $results = Property::whereBetween('price', [1000, 10000]);
    $conditions = [];

    if ($request->has('select_menu')) {
        $conditions['city'] = $request->city;
        $conditions['area'] = $request->area;
        $conditions['purpose'] = $request->status;
        session(['formDataSession' => $conditions]);
    }
    $getSession = session('formDataSession');
    $conditions['city'] = $getSession['city'];
    $conditions['area'] = $getSession['area'];
    $conditions['purpose'] = $getSession['purpose'];
    $results = $results->where($conditions)->paginate(6);

    return view('search', ['page' => 'search', 'results' => $results]);
}
```

Comment: sarnodeep bro actually i have on search function it runs as a two first is when user select form it comes in if condition and second time if user has session for get requests

Comment: Muhammad Irfan, If `select_menu` is null or not set and there is no `formDataSession` key present in the session, the search won't do anything... Is that what you want?

Comment: No bro i have main page i select search options there and then i submit form this time post call hit and search correct according to my code and i save the select form values in session but second time on click page 2 i hit my session condition but this time it return null data

Comment: Hey, do you mind to email me the problem??? we can chat over there... sa87207@gmail.com

Comment: Sorry bro i found the solution for this actully i'm missing something now it's working.